# Lego Racer kit with Chargeable Cars

Tags: set-identification, replacement-parts

I have an old Lego set that I've lost all the documentation on. It's about 10 years old (I see ©2003 in various places). The set built a track and contained two charging stations that integrated into the track. The charging station also counts laps with the green LEDs on top when an infrared beam is broken. The racers were small and electric, but, rather than requiring batteries of their own, they were charged by pushing the racer down on the charging station.

Something has broken in the motor, and it no longer turns, even if I apply 3V directly to it. I haven't been able to find any replacements, but looking without knowing the model number is difficult.

What set is this? Where can I find a replacement motor/car?

[image: charging station and car]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set is 8364, and you can see it here: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8364-1

The motor is part 5313a: (http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=5313a)

Unfortunately, they do not seem to be widely available. The current inventory has one guy selling one as-is (untested) for $10 in the US, and one guy selling a working one for $40 in Israel. You can replace the whole set for a substantially higher price. Sorry I couldn't be of more help for replacing it, but hopefully now that you know the set and part numbers, you can search elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I also found it at http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/5213 under part 5213. Aren't the part numbers standardized by Lego?

Comment: The part numbers are standardized, but many of the parts are hand-entered into these third-party databases. Someone made a mistake, unless Lego released two versions of the set (not unheard of). Lego's official inventory pages (https://service.lego.com/en-us/replacementparts?#WhatBrickBuy/8364) often do not include brand new or rare parts.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This is a common fault with these cars. If the car is dropped hard the magnets inside can shatter making the wheel not turn or be crunchy.

There is a solution. You can buy replacement motors on eBay. The original motors are 6mm diameter by 15mm length. I found some 6mm by 12mm length. They just push out of the gearing housing. Solder two wires, and replacement is complete. My son loves seeing the cars whizzing around. Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the motors found on eBay or some specs for the motors?